# Compile iOS dynamic library(.framework) with cmake

Tags: c++, ios, dynamic, cmake, frameworks

I've compiled a c++ dynamic library using cmake and I want to add to my iOS app. But the header file directory of this .framework is empty, I refer to the CMakeFiles written in the cmake documentation. I don't know where the problem is?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is my CMake script**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

project(Xml C CXX)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Darwin)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(HEADERS
    ./include
)

include_directories(
    ${HEADERS}
)

aux_source_directory(. DIR_SRCS)

add_library(Xml SHARED
    ${DIR_SRCS}
    ${HEADERS}
)

set_target_properties(Xml PROPERTIES
    FRAMEWORK TRUE
    FRAMEWORK_VERSION CXX
    PUBLIC_HEADER ${HEADERS}
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer"
)
```

**Compilation progress**

```
Scanning dependencies of target Xml
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Xml.dir/ILock.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Xml.dir/ParamSet.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Xml.dir/StringConvert.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Xml.dir/XmlFile.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Xml.dir/XmlInterface.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Xml.dir/tinystr.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Xml.dir/tinyxml.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Xml.dir/tinyxmlerror.cpp.o
[ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Xml.dir/tinyxmlparser.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library Xml.framework/Xml
Copying OS X content Xml.framework/Versions/CXX/Headers/include
[100%] Built target Xml
```

[Compiled dynamic library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0cTq.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved. CMake can't get all header files with the `./include` syntax. The following is a modified CMake script.

```
set(HEADERS
    ./include/a.h
    ./include/b.h
    ./include/c.h
)

include_directories(
    ./include
)

aux_source_directory(. DIR_SRCS)

add_library(Xml SHARED
    ${DIR_SRCS}
    ${HEADERS}
)

set_target_properties(Xml PROPERTIES
    FRAMEWORK TRUE
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${HEADERS}"
)
```